# How do you get all the media info for the products?

Tags: magento-1.9, media

I'm pretty new to magento so i'm not sure how to make the call to get all the media info for each product.

I currently have this call that gets all the products and the data on the product model, but I also need the media info.

Any help would be great.

```
$products_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

Comment: I am not sure , but do you want product image urls?

Comment: Yes, that is one thing I will need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of this sample code to get media information of a product.

```
$products_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

foreach ($products_collection as $product) {
    $productGalleryImages = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();

    foreach ($productGalleryImages as $image) {
       var_dump($image); /* Write your logic here */
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be bit faster ...

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
    foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
        var_dump($image->getData());
    }
}
```